# Long Long Decimal Binary Representation using C

Tags: c, long-integer

I've been trying to print out the Binary representation of a long long integer using **C Programming**

My code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<limits.h>

int main()
{
    long long number, binaryRepresentation = 0, baseOfOne = 1, remainder;
    scanf("%lld", &number);
    while(number > 0) {
        remainder = number % 2;
        binaryRepresentation = binaryRepresentation + remainder * baseOfOne;
        baseOfOne *= 10;
        number = number / 2;
    }
    printf("%lld\n", binaryRepresentation);

}
```

The above code works fine when I provide an input of **5** and fails when the number is **9223372036854775807** (0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF).

1.Test Case

```
5
101
```

2.Test Case

```
9223372036854775807
-1024819115206086201
```

Comment: You're trying to contain a long long number in a long long binary representation? Try to use a char array to do that

Comment: The binary representation of 2^63 - 1 is 63 digits long. You're trying to reinterpret this as a decimal number, so of course it's going to overflow a `long long`.

Comment: The binary representation of a long long number is just that number. The internal representation is already binary. So what are you trying to do???

Comment: Your `binaryRepresentation` is getting too big to fit in a `long long` when the number gets big enough. `101` binary is being treated like 101 decimal in that algorithm.

Comment: So what data type should I use for 63 digits long numbers?

Comment: You could either (a) examine the bits most significant first and print them as you go (don't accumulate `binaryRepresentation` or (b) use an array then print the array one element at a time to print the binary representation.

Comment: On (a) above, it's easier to examine the least significant bits first but you can always use recursion (tail recursion?) to print them out in reverse order.

Comment: Try using a char[64]  -> 63 for the digits, and 1 for the terminator.

Comment: @Bathsheba: one way to examine bits in MSB-first order is to use a mask made using `m = ~0ull - ~0ull/2`, and iterate with `m /= 2`.

Comment: @TobySpeight: I'd upvote that. Twice if I could.

Comment: There's really no reason to do this using division. Simply mask out the bits using bitwise operators. This is most readable and guaranteed to be fast. Any solution without `&` and shift is wildly fishy.

Answer (score 2):

Using a denary number to represent binary digits never ends particularly well: you'll be vulnerable to overflow for a surprisingly small input, and all subsequent arithmetic operations will be meaningless.

Another approach is to print the numbers out as you go, but using a recursive technique so you print the numbers in the reverse order to which they are processed:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long output(unsigned long long n)
{
    unsigned long long m = n ? output(n / 2) : 0;
    printf("%d", (int)(n % 2));
    return m;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long long number = 9223372036854775807;
    output(number);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Output:

```
0111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

I've also changed the type to `unsigned long long` which has a better defined bit pattern, and `%` does strange things for negative numbers anyway.

Really though, all I'm doing here is abusing the stack as a way of storing what is really an array of zeros and ones.

Answer (score 1):

Just to spell out some of the comments, the simplest thing to do is use a `char` array to hold the binary digits. Also, when dealing with bits, the bit-wise operators are a little more clear. Otherwise, I've kept your basic code structure.

```
int main()
{
    char bits[64];
    int i = 0;
    unsigned long long number;   // note the "unsigned" type here which makes more sense

    scanf("%lld", &number);

    while (number > 0) {
        bits[i++] = number & 1; // get the current bit
        number >>= 1;         // shift number right by 1 bit (divide by 2)
    }

    if ( i == 0 )   // The original number was 0!
        printf("0");

    for ( ; i > 0; i-- )
        printf("%d", bits[i]);  // or... putchar('0' + bits[i])

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Small nitpick: this doesn't work well with a negative input. Change the type to unsigned long long? But this is otherwise better IMHO than my approach which is little more than an abuse of recursion and stack frames.

Comment: @Bathsheba yes, good nitpick. I rolled with the OPs input type, but it should be unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

As [Bathsheba's answer](/a/48663040) states, you need more space than is 
available if you use a decimal number to represent a bit sequence like that.

Since you intend to print the result, it's best to do that one bit at a time.  We can do this by creating a **mask** with only the highest bit set.  The magic to create this for any type is to complement a zero of that type to get an "all ones" number; we then subtract half of that (i.e. 1111.... - 0111....) to get only a single bit.  We can then shift it rightwards along the number to determine the state of each bit in turn.

Here's a re-worked version using that logic, with the following other changes:

- I use a separate function, returning (like `printf`) the number of characters printed.
- I accept an unsigned value, as we were ignoring negative values anyway.
- I process arguments from the command line - I tend to find that more convenient that having to type stuff on stdin.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int print_binary(unsigned long long n)
{
    int printed = 0;
    /* ~ZERO - ~ZERO/2 is the value 1000... of ZERO's type */
    for (unsigned long long mask = ~0ull - ~0ull/2;  mask;  mask /= 2) {
        if (putc(n & mask ? '1' : '0', stdout) < 0)
            return EOF;
        else
            ++printed;
    }
    return printed;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (int i = 1;  i < argc;  ++i) {
        print_binary(strtoull(argv[i], 0, 10));
        puts("");
    }
}
```

Exercises for the reader:

- Avoid printing leading zeros (hint: either keep a boolean flag that indicates you've seen the first `1`, or have a separate loop to shift the mask before printing).  Don't forget to check that `print_binary(0)` still produces output!
- Check for errors when using `strtoull` to convert the input values from decimal strings.
- Adapt the function to write to a character array instead of stdout.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you really want to achieve, but here is some code that prints the binary representation of a number (change the `typedef` to the integral type you want):

```
typedef int shift_t;
#define NBITS   (sizeof(shift_t)*8)

void printnum(shift_t num, int nbits)
{
    int k= (num&(1LL<<nbits))?1:0;
    printf("%d",k);
    if (nbits) printnum(num,nbits-1);
}
void test(void)
{
    shift_t l;
    l= -1;
    printnum(l,NBITS-1);
    printf("\n");
    l= (1<<(NBITS-2));
    printnum(l,NBITS-1);
    printf("\n");
    l= 5;
    printnum(l,NBITS-1);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to print the digits separately, you could use the following approach:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<limits.h>

void bindigit(long long num);

int main()
{
    long long number, binaryRepresentation = 0, baseOfOne = 1, remainder;
    scanf("%lld", &number);
    bindigit(number);
    printf("\n");

}

void bindigit(long long num) {
  int remainder;
  if (num < 2LL) {
    printf("%d",(int)num);
  } else {
    remainder = num % 2;
    bindigit(num/2);
    printf("%d",remainder);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I tried a code myself with idea from your codes which worked,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
   unsigned long long number;
   int binaryRepresentation[70], remainder, counter, count = 0;
   scanf("%llu", &number);
   while(number > 0) {
       remainder = number % 2;
       binaryRepresentation[count++] = remainder;
       number = number / 2;
   }
   for(counter = count-1; counter >= 0; counter--) {
       printf("%d", binaryRepresentation[counter]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Prefer `CHAR_BITS * sizeof(unsigned long long)` rather than hardcoding 70, although at least one other answerer has fallen for that. Also check the case of `number` being zero (my approach deals with that sloppily by always outputting a leading zero).