# How do I reverse the printing of this for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop

```
for (n=number; n > 0; n=n/2)
{
    if (n % 2 == 0)
        printf ("0");
    else 
        printf ("1");
}
```

Here is part of my code. I have prompted the user for an integer assigned to number and I want to print the binary conversion of the integer. However; currently my code prints the binary digits in reverse (i.e. when I enter 56 it prints 000111 versus 111000). How do I get it to print in reverse?

Comment: Use recursion. .

Comment: Or save digits into an array.

Comment: See my lovely answer (and other lovely answers) to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48662517/long-long-decimal-binary-representation-using-c/48663040#48663040. I use (abuse?) recursion to do this as @coderredoc suggests.

Comment: https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/D3cMxK4Swa

Comment: "I want to print the binary conversion of the integer. " --> this code prints nothing when `number == 0`.  IMO, that is functionally incorrect.  Also  nothing printed when `number < 0`.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of ways you can print the binary equivalent of a integer number.

Here is the my solution using **recursion**.

```
  void call (int n ) {
            if (n > 0 ){
                    call(n/2);/* to prints in reverse order */
                    if(n%2 ==0 )
                            printf ("0");
                    else  
                            printf ("1");
            }
    }
```